# How does one go about implementing a "guest view" for a navigation drawer in Material Design?

Tags: navigation, material-design

Could not find this in Google's guidelines. If one were to develop an app that allows guests to browse (say a simple RSS Feed), would you use the same navigation drawer as if the user were logged in (but change the text to say "Guest" instead of the user's email address?

Example mockup:

[image: guest in navigation drawer mockup]

Are there any examples or webapps built on Material Design that currently has something similar to the above mockup where logging in or registering is not required in order to use the app/site's service?

Comment: What is the UX question?

Comment: To rephrase the question: How would I implement the "guest" view so that users know they can use the app as a guest or log into the site as well without causing too much confusion at the same time follow the Material Design guidelines?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a **Guest**, my understanding is, you have *limited* features available for them when compared to a Registered User who has signed in.

The following is assuming your application heavily depends on a Login, which in the case of an RSS Reader, need not be necessary.

In order to let someone know, they're not yet signed in/registered, the best way I think to do this is **slide the Navigation Drawer out** right at the launch of the application to showcase the limited features and a **Sign In/Register** option in the Drawer, which in the header will be labeled as Guest with the blank profile picture.

Ink the other options gray, if they cannot be accessed by the guest.
**OR**

Keep the options clickable and if the user has not logged in, launch the activity the option intents to and showcase a Fragment to Login, suggesting the feature cannot be accessed by a Guest account and you can log in below. [9GAG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninegag.android.app&hl=en)  App does this very well with NSFW posts.

[image: feature not accessible]

Once logged in, you only need to make the options available if originally you did not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the contents of the navigation drawer ( or your App to be specific ).

Taking your example - the RSS reader - i guess there will be no big difference weather a user is signed in or not. App deals with viewing the contents. There is no addition or editing involved here. In that case both the navigation can be same since there is no change in contents.